How to write this in a rigorous way?
I was studying for a test and encountered the following problem in a textbook:
Suppose $f(x)$ is continuous, with $f >0$ for all $x$ and $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = \lim_{x \to -\infty}f(x)= 0$
Show that there is some number $y$ such that $f(y) \geq f(x)$ for all $x$.
My solution goes like this:
Since $\lim_{x \to \pm \infty} = 0$, there is a large enough $N>0$ such that if $\left|x\right|>N$, then $f(x)<f(N)$.
Then, consider the interval $I=\left[-N,N\right]$. Since$f$ is continuous on $I$, by the extreme value theorem, there exists $y\in I$ such that $f(y) \geq f(x) \forall x\in I$. In particular, $f(y) \geq f(N)$, implying that $f(y)>f(x)$ when $\left|x\right|>N$.
Therefore, $f(y)\geq f(x)\forall x\in \left(-\infty,-N\right)\cup\left[-N,N\right]\cup\left(N,\infty\right) \Rightarrow f(y)\geq f(x) \forall x$.
However, how can I make the argument for the existence of $N$ more rigorous?
Thank you!

You don't need such an $N$: just compare with $f(0)$ instead and your argument is fine

I would proceed as follows: First, prove that the image of $f$ is bounded (I omit the details of that step).
Then, since $M := \sup_{\mathbb R} f$ exists and is not zero (why?), use the definition of $\lim_{x\to \pm\infty} f = 0$ to pick $N$ such that $f(x) < M/2$ when $|x|> N$. Next, find a maximum point $y$ over $[-N,N]$ exactly as you did in your post. Finally, argue that $f(y) = M$.

It seems that your first sentence is the goal of this exercise.  The goal is to show that the image is bounded.  That sentence seems to omit the most important part of the argument...
